Was Basilides's claim about crucifixion ever refuted?
From Wikipedia:

Basilides is reported as having taught a docetic doctrine of Christ's
passion. Although Irenaeus’s makes no mention of Basilides having
written a gospel, he does record him as teaching that Christ in Jesus,
as a wholly divine being, could not suffer bodily pain and did not die
on the cross; but that the person crucified was, in fact, Simon of Cyrene:



He appeared on earth as a man and performed miracles. Thus he himself
did not suffer. Rather, a certain Simon of Cyrene was compelled to
carry his cross for him. It was he who was ignorantly and erroneously
crucified, being transfigured by him, so that he might be thought to
be Jesus. Moreover, Jesus assumed the form of Simon, and stood by
laughing at them.


Has anyone ever refuted this claim made by Basilides, that Simon of Cyrene has died on the cross instead of Jesus?

Yes, in general terms.
The claim that Simon of Cyrene died on the cross instead of Jesus is a specific instance of the more general theory that someone other than Jesus died on the cross.
The more general version has been refuted plenty of times. Scripture itself tells us both that His mother observed Jesus on the cross, and that after His Resurrection, he appeared exhibiting the marks of crucifixion, even urging Thomas to place his (Thomas') hand into His (Jesus') side. This is simply not plausible if Jesus had not been crucified, and further, was not the one whose side was pierced by a spear (an unusual practice which happened because He was already dead when the Romans needed to "move things along").
From various sources, including non-Scriptural sources, we know as a historic "fact" (that is, with as much certainty as can plausibly be given to any account of that period), that someone the authorities believed to be Jesus was crucified. The vast majority of reputable scholars agree on this point. We similarly know that the tomb in which He was laid was subsequently found to be empty; unless we further posit that Simon of Cyrene was not only crucified but also resurrected, that hypothesis cannot also account for the empty tomb.
In any case, the idea that "Jesus did not suffer" is utter nonsense, as attested by his experience in the Garden of Gethsemane. Nowhere in Scripture is it implied that someone else suffered in Jesus' place, whereas it is repeatedly stated that Jesus Himself suffered, was crucified, and died. Not only is this predicted by Isaiah, but it is also the foundation of the Christian faith as repeatedly attested by Paul in particular.
Basilides is either a well-meaning but severely misguided "believer", or an enemy of the Gospel, and the latter have a long history of trying to deny the Resurrection.
Sources:

Negative Evidence for the Resurrection of Christ
The Crucifixion Substitute Theory
The Substitution Theory
Was Someone Else Crucified Instead of Jesus?


As to Basilides specifically, the article you cited already listed some sources that refute his teachings in general. Another source that may be useful for tracking down these earlier refutations is Early Christian Writings: Basilides.


OP: Has anyone ever refuted this claim made by Basilides, that Simon of Cyrene has died on the cross instead of Jesus?

Irenaeus is the source of what we know about Basilides' claim that Simon of Cyrene died on the cross and not Christ Jesus.  Likewise, here is Irenaeus' broad refutation of Basilides claim.

As it has been clearly demonstrated that the Word, who existed in the beginning with God, by whom all things were made, who was also always present with mankind, was in these last days, according to the time appointed by the Father, united to His own workmanship, inasmuch as He became a man liable to suffering, [it follows] that every objection is set aside of those who say, “If our Lord was born at that time, Christ had therefore no previous existence.” For I have shown that the Son of God did not then begin to exist, being with the Father from the beginning; but when He became incarnate, and was made man, He commenced afresh3633 the long line of human beings, and furnished us, in a brief, comprehensive manner, with salvation; so that what we had lost in Adam—namely, to be according to the image and likeness of God—that we might recover in Christ Jesus. Against Heresies Book III Chapter XVIII

Irenaeus then goes on to delineate the arguments that Christ has always existed, came to earth, died, and was resurrected.

indicating that the impassible Christ did not descend upon Jesus, but that He Himself, because He was Jesus Christ, suffered for us; He, who lay in the tomb, and rose again, who descended and ascended,—the Son of God having been made the Son of man, as the very name itself doth declare.  IBID

Irenaeus is clear that Christ Jesus died on the cross.

If, however, He was Himself not to suffer [as Basilides declares], but should fly away from Jesus [or find a substitute], why did He exhort His disciples to take up the cross and follow Him,—that cross which these men represent Him as not having taken up, but [speak of Him] as having relinquished the dispensation of suffering? For that He did not say this with reference to the acknowledging of the Stauros (cross) above, as some among them venture to expound, but with respect to the suffering which He should Himself undergo, and that His disciples should endure, He implies when He says, “For whosoever will save his life, shall lose it; and whosoever will lose, shall find it.” And that His disciples must suffer for His sake, He [implied when He] said to the Jews, “Behold, I send you prophets, and wise men, and scribes: and some of them ye shall kill and crucify.”3652 And to the disciples He was wont to say, “And ye shall stand before governors and kings for My sake; and they shall scourge some of you, and slay you, and persecute you from city to city.”3653 He knew, therefore, both those who should suffer persecution, and He knew those who should have to be scourged and slain because of Him; and He did not speak of any other cross, but of the suffering which He should Himself undergo first, and His disciples afterwards. For this purpose did He give them this exhortation: “Fear not them which kill the body, but are not able to kill the soul; but rather fear Him who is able to send both soul and body into hell;”3654 [thus exhorting them] to hold fast those professions of faith which they had made in reference to Him. IBID

So, after laying out Basilides argument of a replacement in Against Heresies Book I Chapter XXIV, he refutes the claim.
